# Logic Processing in WHERE statement

Tags: sql-server

I need some help in understanding why these two statements are giving me two different results when I think they should've given me the same result:

```
SELECT Field1, SUM(Field2+Field3+Field4) AS AggNum
FROM Table1
WHERE Filter1 IN ('a') 
   AND Filter2 IN ('x','y') OR (Filter2 IN ('z') AND Filter3 IN ('xxx')
GROUP BY Field1
```

vs:

```
SELECT Field1, SUM(Field2+Field3+Field4) AS AggNum
FROM Table1
WHERE Filter1 IN ('a') 
   AND (Filter2 IN ('x','y') OR (Filter2 ='z' AND Filter3 = 'xxx'))
GROUP BY Field1
```

The second query gave me the correct result, but I don't understand how logically the two statements are different. It seemed to me that the () around the AND statement in the where clause shouldn't have mattered at all.

---

Is this just because SQL Server processes this in sequential order?

What happens if I did something like:

```
SELECT Field1, SUM(Field2+Field3+Field4) AS AggNum
FROM Table1
WHERE Filter1 IN ('a') 
   AND Filter2 IN ('x','y') OR (Filter2 ='z' AND Filter3 = 'xxx')
   AND Filter4 = 'd'
GROUP BY Field1
```

so simplified, it would be A and B or C and D... does this mean that the query would return results that are just C and D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that in your real code you have the necessary closing parenthesis so as to not have a syntax error.

Using letters to represent blocks of conditions, we can condense your question to this,

```
WHERE A AND B OR C
```

vs:

```
WHERE A AND (B OR C)
```

In the second statement, A must be true for the conditions to pass.

In the first statement, as long as C is true, it doesn't matter if A or B is true.

Comment: One follow up - what happens if I had WHERE A AND B OR C AND D?

Comment: In that case, as long as C is true, then it doesn't matter if any of the others are true.

Comment: If C is false, then does that mean all the other conditions must be true?

Comment: Yes, if C is false, all the others must be true

Answer (score 0):

Farellia.
The difference is that the last condition in first statement is with "OR" operator, therefore cancelling the others condition.